# Working with paths in Gradle as I replace an Ant build

Tags: gradle

I'm working on a proof of concept for using Gradle to replace an existing Ant build - for Java EE applications - that started simple but has gotten more complex over time. (The Ant build is generic and is controlled by appropriate properties and paths in two files that get imported at the start of the build. It was a good idea, but now is getting a little creaky.)

I have a number of pieces replaced by Gradle right now and it was going well, until I hit the need for one of the defined paths. Paths are great in Ant files as they let you define dependencies just the once and reference them anywhere they're needed.

My search engine foo must be weak today, but I am having trouble finding anywhere that explains how to define something in Gradle that will act like a path and that I can pass around.

Being specific, how do I replace the following path and reference to that path in a Javac Ant task with something that Gradle will use?

First, the path:

```
<path id="base.path">
    <pathelement location="ApacheCommons/commons-lang/commons-lang.jar" />
    <pathelement location="log4j/log4j.jar" />
    <pathelement location="Acme/acme.jar" />
    <fileset dir="." erroronmissingdir="false">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="../../${project.name}Model" erroronmissingdir="false">
        <include name="**/${project.name}Model.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="../../${project.name}Persistance" erroronmissingdir="false">
        <include name="**/${project.name}Persistance.jar"/>
    </fileset>      
    <fileset dir="../../${project.name}Service" erroronmissingdir="false">
        <include name="**/${project.name}Service.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <path refid="server.path" />
</path>
```

Now I grab the path and put it in a Groovy variable:

```
def basePath = ant.properties['base.path']
```

And then use it in the Javac task:

```
ant.javac(srcDir: "${compileSourcecode}", destDir: "WebContent/WEB-INF/classes", source: "${compileSourceversion}", target: "${compileTargetversion}", verbose: "${compileVerbose}", debug: "${compileDebug}", deprecation: "${compileDeprecation}", optimize: "${compileOptimize}", classpathref: "${basePath}", includeAntRuntime: "${compileIncludeAntRuntime}")
```

Except that the basePath variable ends up being null and then nothing compiles.

Comment: So your goal is to reuse the same compile dependencies in different Gradle subprojects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are migrating to Gradle I would recommend setting up your classpath in Gradle itself. The preferred way of managing dependencies in Gradle (as you may already know) is using a dependency repository (Maven or Ivy) and then qualifying it from your `dependencies` closure for each of your gradle projects

```gradle
dependencies{
  compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.2'
  compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.16'
  ...
}
```

However if you must refer to local jar files you have few other options:

#### 1) Set up your own Maven or Ivy repository

It's a quite a bit of work at the start, but may prove more beneficial in the long term.

#### 2) Create a [flat file repository](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#flatDirMulti)

Add this to your `build.gradle`

```gradle
repositories { 
  flatDir{
    dirs 'lib'
  } 
}
```

Put your jars/wars into the lib folder in this format `<name>-<version>.jar` or just `<name>.jar`:

```
e.g.
lib/acme-1.2.3.jar
lib/acme.jar
```

Then you can reference it as you usually would:

```gradle
dependencies{
  ...
  compile 'acme:acme:1.2.3'
  ...
}
```

*Note:* Only dependency name and version are used to look up the jar, and no transitive dependencies are assumed.

#### 3) [Reference the jar files directly](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#file-dependencies)

For example:

```gradle
dependencies{
  ...
  compile file("../../${project.name}Model/${project.name}Model.jar")
  compile fileTree(dir: '../../${project.name}Model', include: '**/*.jar')
  ...
}
```

*Note:* `${project.name}` will resolve to the name of your [gradle project](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html).

All jars added to the `compile` configuration will be automatically available for default compilation tasks such as `classes` and `jar`. You may wish to create a custom [Compile task](http://gradle.org/docs/1.0-milestone-5/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.Compile.html) to replace your current `ant.javac(...)` one in this fashion:

```gradle
task compileSomething(type: Compile){
  source = file("${compileSourcecode}")
  destinationDir = file("WebContent/WEB-INF/classes")
  sourceCompatibility = "${compileSourceversion}"
  targetCompatibility = "${compileTargetversion}"
  options.verbose = "${compileVerbose}".toBoolean()
  options.debug = "${compileDebug}".toBoolean()
  options.optimize = "${compileOptimize}".toBoolean()
  options.deprecation = "${compileDeprecation}".toBoolean()

  classpath = configurations.compile
  // or
  classpath = files('lib/library1.jar')
  // or any combination
  classpath = configuraions.compile + files('lib/library1.jar')
}
```

*Note:* Don't think you can set `includeAntRuntime` but I think it's set to `true` by default.

Of course you can awlays save a list of files in a variable for a more fine-grained reuse:

```gradle
libs = files('lib/library1.jar', 'lib/library2.jar')

dependencies{
  compile libs
}

task compileSomething(type: Compile){
  classpath = libs
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful reply. Unfortunately, the proof of concept investigation has come to a halt, so I cannot continue.